# Run chrome extension in background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am implementing google chrome extension , in which I need to fetch data from some other site through API call and it will take 2-5 seconds to get response, meanwhile if user click somewhere out of extension body ( to close the extension ) then fetch is terminated.

So is there any option by which I can overtake this issue ?

Basically I want that chrome extension make fetch API call in background even after closing the extension.

Comment: Use the [background script + messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/migrating_to_service_workers/).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.